# Three.js Physijs move mesh towards mouse?

Tags: javascript, three.js, physijs

So i've been sifting through posts on here and the docs to try and figure out how to get a BoxMesh to essentially follow the mouse. Eventually i'll do joystick touch controls, similar to Heroes of Loot, or other games that use a touch joystick. But for now I want to ensure I can get directional velocity working properly.

So here's what i have in my mouse down event:

```
if (scene.mouseControls.isDown) {
  var coords = scene.mouseControls.screenCoords;
  var vector = new THREE.Vector3();

  vector.set(
    ( scene.mouseControls.screenCoords.x / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
    0.5,
    - ( scene.mouseControls.screenCoords.y / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1
  );
  vector.unproject(scene.camera);

  var p1 = this.mesh.position;
  var p2 = vector;
  var angle = Math.atan2(p2.x - p1.x, p2.z - p1.z);
  var velX = Math.sin(angle) * 20;
  var velZ = Math.cos(angle) * 20;

  console.log(vector.x, vector.z);

  this.mesh.setLinearVelocity(new THREE.Vector3(velX, 0, velZ));
}
else {
  this.mesh.setLinearVelocity(notMovingVector);
}
```

What happens though is the determined velocity seems to flip back and forth, so the player is very very jittery.

Here's how I set mouse coords:

```
window.addEventListener(activeEventList[POINTER_MOVE], function (e) {
  if (e.touches) {
    var t = e.touches[0];
    _this.screenCoords.x = t.clientX;
    _this.screenCoords.y = t.clientY;
  }
  else {
    _this.screenCoords.x = e.clientX;
    _this.screenCoords.y = e.clientY;
  }
});
```

Not using scroll offset or anything, as the scene is full screen.

**Edit**

Removed the previous direction code. Using atan2 to calculate an angle, and apply that instead. Similar to how ive done this in 2d games.

Comment: As you're targeting a joystick in the end anyway, you could just skip the mouse biz and use e.g. arrowkeys to push the object - that's what you'd then do with the joystick anyway, right? For what happens with the mouse would be easier to understand what's happening if you had a working demo on-line which could test & debug .. still trying to read a bit but didn't get it like that yet. Should be simple enough though.

Comment: With the joystick controls on touch, what i plan to do is first touch is origin point. Then dragging in any direction from that origin is the considered direction to move in. Fixed buttons on touch can be a pain, especially on different device sizes.

Comment: Ok got that - thought earlier that you targeted one of those touch-emulated virtual gamepad stick like widgets.

Comment: kinda similar i guess, in the sense of going all directions, not just up/down/left/right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure this out. My change to use atan2 was a step in the right direction, but it needed the multiplyScalar back. The thing is I am using the cameras X & Y values to calculate distance. But visually, its X & Y covers more space than down at the plane.

So here's what i did:

```
if (scene.mouseControls.isDown) {
  var coords = scene.mouseControls.screenCoords;
  var vector = new THREE.Vector3();

  vector.set(
    ( scene.mouseControls.screenCoords.x / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
    - ( scene.mouseControls.screenCoords.y / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1,
    0.5
  );
  vector.unproject(scene.camera);

  var dir = vector.sub(scene.camera.position).normalize();
  var distance = - scene.camera.position.y / dir.y;

  var p1 = this.mesh.position;
  var p2 = scene.camera.position.clone().add(dir.multiplyScalar(distance));

  var angle = Math.atan2(p2.z - p1.z, p2.x - p1.x);
  var velX = Math.cos(angle) * 20;
  var velZ = Math.sin(angle) * 20;

  this.mesh.setLinearVelocity(new THREE.Vector3(velX, 0, velZ));
}
```